# As an Albanian studying in Italy, how can I apply for a tourist visa for the UK to visit my friends?

Tags: italy, standard-visitor-visas, albanian-citizens

I'm an Albanian citizen pursuing a PhD in Italy where I have a residence permit (*permesso di soggiorno*).

How can I apply for a tourist visa for the UK to visit my friends?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks basic research.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to fill out an online application and pay the £85 here for a **Standard Visitor Visa**:

> https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

Note that:

> You’ll need to have your fingerprints and photograph (known as
>   ‘biometric information’) taken at a [visa application centre](https://www.gov.uk/find-a-visa-application-centre) as part of
>   your application.